# Origin of terms "sensitivity" and "specificity"

Tags: terminology, history, sensitivity-specificity

Who coined the terms "sensitivity" and "specificity"—meaning the complements of false positives, and false negatives, respectively in tests and measures—and when did they first do so?

Bonus points if there is a motivating etymology.

Comment: Any retreat from this? Yerushalmy, J. 1947. Statistical Problems in Assessing Methods of Medical Diagnosis, with Special Reference to X-Ray Techniques. _Public Health Reports_  62(40), 1432-1449. doi:10.2307/4586294

Comment: @NickCox Gilman, R. L., Boerner, F., & Lukens, M. (1940). A SIMPLIFIED COMPLEMENT FIXATION TECHNIC FOR THE DIAGNOSIS AND TREATMENT OF SYPHILIS: ITS SENSITIVITY AND SPECIFICITY. *Archives of Dermatology and Syphilology*, 41(1), 32-37. is certainly earlier. :)

Comment: You got me there. I just Googled and found a confident assertion that Yerushalmy was first, which is evidently wrong. I've found a few earlier occurrences before documented first occurrences myself for quite different terms. .

Comment: As far as etymology, it makes the most sense in a medical sense (I don't have a source, this is just how it was taught to me), when viewing the terms as relative to the desire to detect an illness. How well does a test Sense the presence of an illness? How Specific is the test in detecting the illness? Is it highly specific or all over the place?

Comment: I thought the terms came from radar operation in World War Two. The “receiver operator” in receiver operator characteristic curve was the operator of a radar who was looking for enemy planes.

Comment: @TannerPhillips "How Specific is the test in detecting the illness?" **Specificity** is about detecting **not** the illness.

Comment: I wonder if this goes back as far as the first telling of the Princess and the Pea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr (this answer is a bit of a book report): The terms *sensitivity* and *specificity* have their origin in the roots of immunology in the first years of the 20th century, and work towards antibody testing for syphilis.**

As @NickCox and others in the published literature have suggested (e.g., Lilienfield, 2007), Yerushalmy was an exponent of the biostatistical concepts of sensitivity and specificity in a 1947 article on radiological tests for tuberculosis. However, it is reasonably easy to find earlier uses of these terms in the context of medical tests (e.g., Gilman, Boerner, and Lukens, 1940) using academic search engines.

In the 2021 article by Binney, Hyde, and Bossuyt cited by @PeterMilne (and well worth the read!), the authors trace the genesis of these terms' use to immunology, and

> the development of serology in the early 20th century. They are closely linked to the development of the [Wassermann reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassermann_test) as a test for syphilis, and to notions of species of pathogen and of specific disease entities. […Where it was] used to distinguish diseased from non-diseased patients.

The terms were already in established use in the syphilis serology literature by the late 30s and early 40s. According to these authors, the concepts of sensitivity and specificity spread to disciplines like clinical epidemiology (and presumably from there to other epidemiologies :)—including for other diseases, such as tuberculosis, decision making in medicine, and disciplines where evaluating tests is important.

According to Binney, Hyde, & Bossuyt, the term **specificity** has its origins in experiments around 1901 demonstrating the capacity for blood serum from a living animal previously exposed to a known pathogen to successfully destroy that **specific** pathogen (in contrast to other pathogens). They go on to describe [Jules Jean Baptiste Vincent Bordet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Bordet)'s advancement of the immunological concepts of **antibody** and **complement** from this specific destructive power, where antibodies were described by him as a mechanism to **sensitize** an organism's immune response to a specific pathogen. From these definitions, Binney, Hyde, & Bossuyt argue, come the concept that “specific entities must be determined to identify infected individuals,” and the development of the Wasserman antibody test<sup>*</sup> first embodied these concepts in technology. These authors cite work by Craig a few years later in 1910 presenting tables of numbers testing positive and negative among cases of syphilis, and percent testing positive among cases of syphilis, where the term **specificity of the test** was used to describe “healthy individuals in whom [syphilis] could be absolutely excluded, we tested seventy individuals, with a negative result in every instance.”

The concept of **sensitivity of the test** has a blurrier origin, with Binney, Hyde, and Bossuyt writing:

> Through the 1920s, the term “sensitive” referred both to the fraction of true positives and, sometimes in the same article, to the delicacy of an immunologic reaction: its propensity to return positive reactions, whether these were true or false positives.

They note that this overloaded meaning extended through to the 40s in the literature, until 1942 when American immunologist Reuben Leon Kahn wrote “Strictly speaking, the term ‘sensitivity’ when used in connection with tests for syphilis should apply only to cases of syphilis.”

<sup>*</sup> The Wasserman test is not actually specific immunologically, but is diagnostically useful.

**References**

Craig, C.F. (1910). [Observations upon the Noguchi modification of the Wassermann complement fixation test in the diagnosis of lues in the military service](https://rupress.org/jem/article-pdf/12/6/726/493639/726.pdf). *Journal of Experimental Medicine*. *12*, 726–45.

Gilman, R. L., Boerner, F., & Lukens, M. (1940). [A Simplified Complement Fixation Technic for the Diagnosis and Treatment Of Syphilis: Its Sensitivity and Specificity](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/article-abstract/519377). *Archives of Dermatology and Syphilology*, *41*(1), 32–37.

Kahn, R. L. (1942). *Serology in Syphilis Control: Principles of Sensitivity and Specificity, With an Appendix for Health Ofﬁcers and Industrial Physicians*. Williams & Wilkins.

Lilienfeld, D. E. (2007). [Abe and Yak: the interactions of Abraham M. Lilienfeld and Jacob Yerushalmy in the development of modern epidemiology (1945-1973)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20486411). *Epidemiology*. *18*, 507–14.

Yerushalmy, J. (1947). [Statistical problems in assessing methods of medical diagnosis, with special reference to X-ray techniques](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4586294). *Public Health Reports*. *62*,1432–1449.

Answer (score 2):

Binney, N., C. Hyde and P. M. Bossuyt. ‘On the origin of sensitivity and specificity’. Annals of Internal Medicine, 174 (2021): 401–7. 10.7326/M20-5028.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/308321)